# Can't show verses in label

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, random, struct

**I am trying to show a random item of an array, I have this file:**

```
//VerseModel.swift

import Foundation

struct VerseModel { 
   var verse = ""
   var reference = ""
   var date = Date()

}
```

**This file:**

```
//VersesMock.swift

import Foundation

struct VersesMock {
    var verses: Array<VerseModel> = [
        VerseModel(verse: "Teste 1", reference: "Mt 13:2", date: Date()),
        VerseModel(verse: "Teste 2", reference: "Mt 14:2", date: Date()),
        VerseModel(verse: "Teste 3", reference: "Mt 15:2", date: Date()),
        VerseModel(verse: "Teste 4", reference: "Mt 16:2", date: Date()),
        VerseModel(verse: "Teste 5", reference: "Mt 17:2", date: Date()),
        VerseModel(verse: "Teste 6", reference: "Mt 18:2", date: Date()),
        VerseModel(verse: "Teste 7", reference: "Mt 19:2", date: Date()),
        VerseModel(verse: "Teste 8", reference: "Mt 20:2", date: Date()),
        VerseModel(verse: "Teste 9", reference: "Mt 21:2", date: Date())
    ]
}
```

**And this:**

```
import UIKit

final class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var verseLbl: UILabel!

var user = UserMock()
var verses = VersesMock().verses

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    nameLabel.text = user.name
    verseLbl.text = verseModel
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

I am trying to do something like this, but it says

> "Cannot assign value of type '[VerseModel]' to type 'String?'"

Yeah, I know I can't assign they because are from different types, so how can I assign them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`randomElement()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994747-randomelement) which was *introduced* in **Swift 4.2**.

```
verseLbl.text = verses.randomElement()?.verse
```

Comment: @LucasOliveiraFerreira and?

Comment: "Cannot assign value of type '[VerseModel]' to type 'String?'"

Comment: @LucasOliveiraFerreira check the answer carefully please.

Comment: Sorry, I'm almost sleeping on my keyboard.

Comment: @LucasOliveiraFerreira i’ve been there. :’D

Answer (score 1):

In `HomeViewController` class you can try assigning random values to `verseLbl` using `Int.random`[for example], and instead of assigning `verseModel` you should assign verse object of `VersesMock` class, like

```
var verses = VersesMock().verses

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let count = verses.count
    let randomIndex = Int.random(in: 0...(count - 1)) //or use your specific array index
    nameLabel.text = user.name
    verseLbl.text = verses[randomIndex].verse
}
```